Extract Text From Between Two Points in a String of Text In a Column?
I have a table which contains thousands of rows and multiple columns, one of the columns contains an XML message in text format put there via an internal process.
Below is a single row extract from said column containing the XML string:
<XXXAlertMessage>
    <XXXAlertCode>XXX</XXXAlertCode>
    <XXXAlert>
        <XXXaaaXXXaaaXXX>
            <XXXXXXaaaXXXaaaXXX>
                    <XXXID>XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX</XXXID>
                <XXXType>GXXXXXE</XXXType>
                <MPxNs>
                    <ImportMPxN>7432921709</ImportMPxN>
                </MPxNs>
            </XXXXXXaaaXXXaaaXXX>
        </XXXaaaXXXaaaXXX>
    </XXXAlert>
</XXXAlertMessage>

I am trying to update my Oracle SQL query to extract from the XML column, just the value between the two <ImportMPxN> tags, the value is a different length in each row on the database, so looking for the first <ImportMPxN> and then counting / extracting a set number of characters to the right, unfortunately doesn't work for this.
The table is called "Transaction" and the column is called "XML",
My basic query currently is:
Select XML from Transaction;

I have tried a number of options however currently I am at a loss for a solution ...
I've done some googling and found the following thread:
Oracle SQL: Extracting text between two characters
However I've tried a few things which are suggested but I'm still drawing a blank ...
I've also tried:
with test_data (raw_text)
as
(select xml from transaction)
select
regexp_substr(raw_text,'\<ImportMPxN>([^<ImportMPxN>]+)\<ImportMPxN>',1,1,null,1) as xml
from
test_data;

The query runs ok, however it returns an empty column (no results).
I'm kind of at a loss now and require some help, advice or assistance on how to extract the value I need.

Is there a reason you aren't using the built-in XML-handling functions, like XMLQuery()? What data type is the column; and if it's varchar2 or CLOB, are all the values in it always well-formed XML?

Hi Alex, yeah unfortunately my SQL query skills are a bit limited at the moment and I do keep having to seek help from my work colleagues. I'm learning as I go along and they are coming along slowly but surely :o) I'll certainly be looking into the XMLQuery() function you mention in order to gain knowledge, thanks ever so much for your help and advice, it really is much appreciated :o)

Hi Alex, apologies that you had to edit my post, appreciate your help and support :o)

Rather than trying to manipulate the XML as a string, which rarely ends well, you can use the built-in XMLQuery function:
select xmlquery('//MPxNs/ImportMPxN/text()'
  passing xmltype(xml)
  returning content).getstringval() as ImportMPxN
from transaction;




IMPORTMPXN




7432921709



fiddle
Based on your description I've assumed the column is varchar2 or CLOB, rather than XMLType; so there is an xmltype() call within that to convert it from a plain string for processing.
I've included the parent node in the XPath as //MPxNs/ImportMPxN/text(), which means it will find the text of the ImportMPxN as a child of a MPxNs node. If it won't always have the same parent you could use //ImportMPxN/text(), and if the whole structure is always the same you could specify it explicitly (instead of starting with //...). With only one example value it's hard to tell.
This also assumes that all the values in that column are either null or well-formed XML. And that they have at most one matching node.
If you want to extract multiple values from each XML document you can look at using XMLTable instead.
You can read more about Oracle's XML capabilities in the documentation.

As mentioned by @AlexPoole, you can also use XMLTABLE to query the row:
SELECT x.*
FROM   transaction t
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         '//MPxNs'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(t.xml)
         COLUMNS
           importmpxn VARCHAR2(20) PATH './ImportMPxN'
       ) x;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE transaction (xml) AS
SELECT '<XXXAlertMessage>
    <XXXAlertCode>XXX</XXXAlertCode>
    <XXXAlert>
        <XXXaaaXXXaaaXXX>
            <XXXXXXaaaXXXaaaXXX>
                    <XXXID>XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX</XXXID>
                <XXXType>GXXXXXE</XXXType>
                <MPxNs>
                    <ImportMPxN>7432921709</ImportMPxN>
                </MPxNs>
            </XXXXXXaaaXXXaaaXXX>
        </XXXaaaXXXaaaXXX>
    </XXXAlert>
</XXXAlertMessage>' FROM DUAL

Outputs:



IMPORTMPXN




7432921709



and:
SELECT x.*
FROM   transaction t
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         '/XXXAlertMessage'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(t.xml)
         COLUMNS
           xxxalertcode VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'XXXAlertCode',
           xxxid        VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'XXXAlert/XXXaaaXXXaaaXXX/XXXXXXaaaXXXaaaXXX/XXXID',
           xxxtype      VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'XXXAlert/XXXaaaXXXaaaXXX/XXXXXXaaaXXXaaaXXX/XXXType',
           importmpxn   VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'XXXAlert/XXXaaaXXXaaaXXX/XXXXXXaaaXXXaaaXXX/MPxNs/ImportMPxN'
       ) x;

Outputs:



XXXALERTCODE
XXXID
XXXTYPE
IMPORTMPXN




XXX
XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
GXXXXXE
7432921709




As an academic exercise (i.e. don't use this), if you did want to get the value using string functions (don't, use a proper XML parser) and you want to:

extract a single value
from a properly formed XML leaf element
where the start- and end-tags are not going to appear anywhere else in the string

Then you can use:
SELECT SUBSTR(
         xml,
         INSTR(xml, '<ImportMPxN>') + LENGTH('<ImportMPxN>'),
         INSTR(xml, '</ImportMPxN>')
         - INSTR(xml, '<ImportMPxN>')
         - LENGTH('<ImportMPxN>')
       ) AS ImportMPxN
FROM   transaction

or:
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         xml,
         '<ImportMPxN>(\d+)</ImportMPxN>',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS ImportMPxN
FROM   transaction

fiddle
